# How to get post_id from post_meta

Tags: wordpress

How can we get `post_id` from `post_meta` by given `meta_key`,

I want to get post_id from post_meta where meta_key is :

> _wp_page_template

and meta_value is

> my_page_template.php

Would like some help please.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you planning to do? If you really want to use this sctructure, you could do a simple wpquery for that

Comment: @Rochester Oliveira i want to di it with `get_metadata(---)` please help how can i do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this in your functions.php an then call it when you want

```
 function getIdFromMeta( $meta_key, $meta_value ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $pid = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_value = '$meta_value' AND meta_key = '$meta_key' ORDER BY post_id DESC") );
    if( $pid != '' )
        return $pid;
    else 
        return false;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Anyone know how this would look for postgresql. I'm getting an error.